# How to get the type parameters of a Roslyn TypeSyntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

How can I get the type parameters of a `TypeSyntax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `TypeSyntax` represents a generic type, it will be an instance of `GenericNameSyntax`. You can get the type parameters in one line:

```
var typeParamsOrNull = (typeSyntax as GenericNameSyntax)?.TypeArgumentList.Arguments;
```